# cdc_acm 1-1:1.0: acm_port_activate - usb_submit_urb(ctrl irq) failed

Tags: drivers, usb, arduino

I am trying to connect the arduino uno to the arduino Idle, but I've got troubles and I don't have any ideas how to fix it.

Thats the message from dmesg.

```
[ 4622.287543] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[ 4622.287545] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[ 4624.838157] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 4624.989836] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 4624.989846] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[ 4624.989852] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[ 4624.989857] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 7583033383835121A102
[ 4624.992913] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 4650.032978] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: acm_port_activate - usb_submit_urb(ctrl irq) failed
```

Is anyone had theses experiense too?
I will be grateful for any sugestions

Comment: Starting with OS & release details is usually a good start.  You've tagged *drivers* which are kernel modules; but we've not details as to what software stack you're actually using (LTS releases offer two stacks too)

Answer (score 2):

I had this as well, finally tracked it down to the kernel update from 5.4.0-73-generic to 5.4.0-74-generic on or around 10th June.

I used Grub to boot into 5.4.0-73 and all worked fine

This was on 20.04.2 LTS